# Are vertical dots rigorous?

Tags: proof-writing

If I'm doing a proof and I use vertical dots or specifically say something like "carrying on in this way until", is that considered a rigorous proof?

Here's a relatively simple example of what I mean from group theory.  Let's say I want to prove that for every $a_1, a_2, \dots , a_n\in G$, $$(a_1a_2\cdots a_n)^{-1} = a_n^{-1}\cdots a_2^{-1}a_1^{-1}$$
Here's how I might do it:

> Let $a_1,\dots, a_n\in G$ with $n$ some positive integer.  Then to show $(a_1\cdots a_n)^{-1} = a_n^{-1}\cdots a_1^{-1}$, it suffices to show that $(a_1\cdots a_n)(a_n^{-1}\cdots a_1^{-1}) = e$.  Using the generalized associative law, we see that $$\begin{align*} (a_1\cdots a_n)(a_n^{-1}\cdots a_1^{-1}) &= (a_1\cdots a_{n-1})(a_na_n^{-1})(a_{n-1}^{-1}\cdots a_1^{-1}) \\ &= (a_1\cdots a_{n-1})(a_{n-1}^{-1}\cdots a_1^{-1}) \\ &= (a_1\cdots a_{n-2})(a_{n-1}a_{n-1}^{-1})(a_{n-2}^{-1}\cdots a_1^{-1}) \\ &\ \ \ \ \ \vdots \\ &=a_1a_1^{-1} \\ &= e\end{align*}$$ concluding the proof.

To be considered rigorous should I explicitly use an induction proof, or is this considered an appropriate argument?

Comment: Vertical dots are not a proof technique, they are notation, as such the word "rigorous" does not apply to them. If you mean "are they well-defined" I'm sure you could give a cumbersome definition in formal logic, yes, as they are just shorthand for induction.

Comment: I guess I'm mostly asking if other mathematicians consider the type of proof I gave to be sufficient.  As I'm learning math on my own, I don't have a professor to grade and comment on my work.

Comment: You should use mathematical induction for this type of theorems. Without it you can't say that you proved this theorem.

Comment: @Adam OK.  That's good to know.  Thank you.

Comment: You may find some extremely pedantic individuals who might pick at your choice of notation, and I think it's a bit informal, but professionals use this all the time in lectures. Perhaps the best "rule of thumb" here is to try and confine the more informal notation to talks and lectures.